# Replacing text with a defined text

Tags: powershell

I have a text file which contains the following

```
php_configuration=up21
sql_configuration=up22
apache_configuration=up23
java_script=down
html=down
```

I want to replace the `up21`, `up22` and `up23` with `cat`, `dog` and `elephant` and keep the remaining content of the file as it is.

But when I execute the below powershell script, it will replace the strings, but wont preserve the remaining content of the text file:

```bsh
$a=Get-Content -Path C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Pow\loc.txt |Select-String -Pattern 
    "php_configuration"|ForEach-Object {$_ -Replace 'up21', 'cat'}
          
        
$b=Get-Content -Path C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Pow\loc.txt |Select-String -Pattern 
    "sql_configuration"|ForEach-Object {$_ -Replace 'up22', 'dog'}
        
$c=Get-Content -Path C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Pow\loc.txt |Select-String -Pattern 
    "apache_configuration"|ForEach-Object {$_ -Replace 'up23', 'elephant'}
        
$a, $b, $c| Set-Content -Path C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Pow\loc.txt
```

Comment: That is because you pipe `$a, $b, $c` into `Set-Content` without the rest of the text. Did you try to `Get-Content` the whole file and save that in a variable, then `-Replace` those strings and finally `Set-Content`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can basically do like:

```
(Get-Content 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Pow\loc.txt') | Foreach-Object {
 $_ -replace 'up21', 'cat' `
    -replace 'up22', 'dog' `
    -replace 'up23', 'elephant'
 } | Set-Content 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Pow\loc.txt'
```

Is there a need to specify "php_configuration" etc.?

EDIT: Ok, after reading @T-Me's comment below, I have changed the answer. Not the prettiest but here you go.

```
(Get-Content 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Pow\loc.txt') | Foreach-Object {
     if($_ | Select-string -Pattern "php_configuration"){$_ -replace 'up21', 'cat'}
     elseif($_ | Select-String -Pattern "sql_configuration"){$_ -replace 'up22', 'dog'}
     elseif($_ | Select-String -Pattern "apache_configuration"){$_ -replace 'up23', 'elephant'}
     else {$_}
     } | Set-Content 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Pow\loc.txt'
```

Comment: I would assume that the `up`s are variable and you don't want to change the script every time. So he can use `Select-String -Pattern ` to identfy the whole row. For capturing the `up`s he would need a regex in the `-replace`